# I am forced to append my widget outside of <body>. What are the side-effect of doing so?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am in a strange situation. I am a widget developer and one of my client is using my widget (written in `svelte`) on their website.

Unfortunately their website, written in `wordpress` has some strange `MutationObserver` code in it. The callback of `MutationObserver` actually messes up with my widget when any `DOM` nodes are changed. Following is the culprit code (comes from a plugin called twemoji):

```
const cb = function (records) {
                    for (var addedNodes, removedNodes, length, a, r = records.length; r--;) {
                        if (addedNodes = records[r].addedNodes, removedNodes = records[r].removedNodes, 1 === (length = addedNodes.length) && 1 === removedNodes.length && 3 === addedNodes[0].nodeType && "IMG" === removedNodes[0].nodeName && addedNodes[0].data === removedNodes[0].alt && "load-failed" === removedNodes[0].getAttribute("data-error")) return;
                        for (; length--;) {
                            if (3 === (a = addedNodes[length]).nodeType) {
                                if (!a.parentNode) continue;
                                for (; a.nextSibling && 3 === a.nextSibling.nodeType;) {

                                    //******** culprit code ********
                                    a.nodeValue = a.nodeValue + a.nextSibling.nodeValue, a.parentNode.removeChild(a.nextSibling)

                                }
                                a = a.parentNode
                            }

                        }
                    }
                };
 const x = new MutationObserver(cb).observe(document.body, {childList: !0, subtree: !0}), f(document.body)
```

---

Since above code is observing entire `body`, to avoid this code my `widget.js` should append my widget outside of the `<body>` like this.

```
<head>
  <script src="path-to-my/widget.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<div id="my-widget"></div>
```

My question is:

1. Are there any side-effect of appending my widget outside of `<body>`?
2. Is there any other solution to protect my widget from this code? (I can't use `IFrame`).
3. If I were to use `shadow-dom` to encapulate my widget, would it solve the problem?

Comment: Silly solution, not recommended except for unofficial things like userscripts: monkeypatch it back so that their MutationObserver doesn't get in the way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't begin to think how would I do that. If effectively changes the nodes that are being tracked by framework (svelte). Even if I could do that, it would be a lot of work and many edge cases.

Comment: Does the observer do anything useful for you? If not, you could try just deleting `window.MutationObserver` before it runs, or make it a no-op.

Comment: Does the observer do anything useful for you? - not at all. 
But the problem is, its not my website. Client just appends my scripts, after twemoji code. My script appends widget.  I can't made any changes or delete any code in client's website. Nor I should do anything to impact other part of the website

Comment: If it doesn't do anything useful for the client, and your script can run before the observer gets attached, you can effectively disable the observer. You don't have to *delete* any code for this to work, you just have to add your own code at the right place.

Comment: It doesn't do anything useful for my widget. For clients website, I think it shows emojis. Sorry if I miscommunicated.