# IE: input not working when appended after the <body>

Tags: javascript, html

Following input doesnt work in IE. You can't type in it

```html
<script>
    document.body.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", document.createElement("INPUT"));
</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea if any workaround will fix it?

Note: textarea works fine if appended this way.

Edit: you can test here in IE11: https://bolder-field-technosaurus.glitch.me/

Comment: Hello. What does "doesnt work" mean? Not displayed? textarea is added to IE11 by `insertAdjacentElement()` method?

Comment: I clearly wrote: "You can't type in it". It gets appended correctly. Only problem is that you can't type in it.

Comment: I have no idea why its getting downvoted so much. **Any** feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Elements can't be outside the body tag in an HTML document. "afterend" creates the input element after (outside) the the parent element - which is body tag in this case.
So you may want to use "beforeend" instead so that it can be created just before the closing body tag.

See MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement

You'll also see there in the browser compatibility section that it doesn't support all elements in IE Though it specifically mentions svg element...
I'm not sure why it doesn't work for input though.

Comment: "Elements can't be outside the body tag in an HTML document" Do you have a source for this? My use case is such that input must be appended outside the body.

Comment: @dasfdsa What is the use case? Could you briefly describe it?

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn Thanks for asking. I described my usecase in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783759/i-am-forced-to-append-my-widget-outside-of-body-what-are-the-side-effect-of-d. In summery, if I put my code inside body some other code messes up with it.

Comment: "<head> and <body> make up the only two elements that fall directly inside <html>" according to this source: https://css-tricks.com/html-vs-body-in-css/

Comment: @dasfdsa If the client's code does not do anything useful to your widget, what does it affect your widget? How bad is it that you can't put your widget inside the `<body>` tag?

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn It replaces my nodes by its clones. None of my event handlers fire. Its pretty bad as you can tell

Comment: I think you should try to read the client's code and find if you can try something that would make it list your widget into the white list. If you can't find any way to make your code into the white list, then I think you can use the `<p>` or any tags as an input with event listener (pretty bad idea, but works)